# Blender with Digital Ocean?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Digital Ocean offer SSD cloud servers. Is it possible to run Blender on one? If so, what is needed?

Thanks,

Comment: Hum not sure what type of Cloud server that is or what services they offer, but this doesn't sound like a question about Blender, itself, more like a question for their support team. Could you please clarify, is this a question about Blender?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't sound like a question about Blender itself

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible to run Blender on a DigitalOcean server. That being said, I wouldn't recommend it as it's pretty expensive if you want good performance and fast render times.

Here's how to install Blender on a DigitalOcean droplet:

- Download the latest 64-bit version of Blender (choose the right one for your droplet)
- Move the file to `/usr/local` and unzip it
- Add Blender to the PATH variable
- Install some missing libraries. There's a how-to guide on which packages you'll need here: [Installing Blender on a virtual server](http://www.elaspix.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Blog/Renderfarm/howto_install_Blender_EC2_64bit.pdf)
- Once everything's installed, you'll want to run your render via the command line: `./blender -b path/to/your/file.blend --engine CYCLES [the rest of the render options]`

I toyed around with the idea of building a DigitalOcean-based render farm. After a few tests I concluded that it would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Did you find another service over DigitalOcean?

Comment: @BlenderGreenhorn No, I didn't really do much more research. My university has over 100 lab computers that I can connect to and render on, so I don't really need a cloud-based rendering system right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Though how much you can do may depend on the resources of the droplet you spin up.

If you need to run relatively simple scripts against the python api (i.e. load a `.py` script from the command line) you can do this on the `s-1vcpu-2gb` or what the droplet resize UI currently says is:

- Basic / Regular Intel
- 1 vCPU / 2 GB memory

Though it may be tempting to use one of the headless docker images, I wasn't able to get those images to run, possibly due to memory limitations.

However, you can successfully install it on a 1-click ubuntu 20.04 / docker digital ocean template using:

```
snap install blender --classic
```

```sh
# Validate binary location
which blender
# Test execution
/snap/bin/blender --version
```

If you get an error:

```sh
/snap/blender/4036/blender: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You may also need to install some dependencies:

```
apt install libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
```